# How to insert field from a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I insert a field from a subquery. The code is below. I want to add in the date of birth for the oldest child on each policy. I am getting an error saying I can't insert null values into the target table. I tried to alter the column to accept null values but that didn't work either. If you have any other ideas to do this insert into the target table I would really appreciate the help!

```
Insert into JOURNEY_1A t (oldestchild_dob)
select A.oldestchild_dob
FROM
(
select DISTINCT T.POLICY_ID, max( M.ME_BIRTH_DATE) AS OLDESTCHILD_DOB
from JOURNEY_1A t, ALL_MTH S, member M
WHERE T.POLICY_ID = S.POLICY_ID
AND S.MONTH_ID = (SELECT MAX(MONTH_ID) FROM ALL_MTH )
AND S.MEMBER_ID = M.MEMBER_ID
AND trunc((to_date(sysdate)-m.me_birth_date)/365.25) BETWEEN 0 AND 17
AND M.ME_BIRTH_DATE IS NOT NULL 
group by t.policy_id
) A
JOIN JOURNEY_1A T
ON A.POLICY_ID = T.POLICY_ID
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want a correlated `UPDATE` and not an `INSERT` as you are trying to modify (update) a value in an existing row and not create (insert) a new row.

```sql
UPDATE JOURNEY_1A t 
SET  oldestchild_dob = ( SELECT max( M.ME_BIRTH_DATE)
                         FROM   ALL_MTH S
                                INNER JOIN member M
                                ON S.MEMBER_ID = M.MEMBER_ID
                         WHERE  T.POLICY_ID = S.POLICY_ID
                         AND    S.MONTH_ID = (SELECT MAX(MONTH_ID) FROM ALL_MTH )
                         AND    m.me_date_of_birth > ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -18*12)
                       );
```

*Note: untested as we do not have your tables.*

*Note: the `M.ME_BIRTH_DATE IS NOT NULL` filter is not necessary as you already test that `M.ME_BIRTH_DATE` is in the last 18 years and cannot be `NULL` if it matches that filter.*

*Note: Do not try to calculate age using 365.25 days-per-year as you will get edge-cases where the calculation includes or excludes someone who is almost 18 when it should not. Use `ADD_MONTHS` to subtract 18 years from today and use that as the boundary (or use `MONTHS_BETWEEN`).*

---

Your code does not work because `INSERT` will try to insert a new row (it does not insert a new value into an existing row) and because you are only specifying a single column then the database will use the default value for all the other columns of that row. If you have not specified a default value then `NULL` is used.

This means that:

```sql
Insert into JOURNEY_1A t (oldestchild_dob) VALUES (DATE '2023-01-01');
```

is the same as:

```sql
Insert into JOURNEY_1A t (policy_id, col1, col2, oldestchild_dob)
  VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DATE '2023-01-01');
```

which is probably going to be resolved as:

```sql
Insert into JOURNEY_1A t (policy_id, col1, col2, oldestchild_dob)
  VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, DATE '2023-01-01');
```

and the `NULL` value issue is for all the columns you do not specify, and not the one column that you do specify.

If you do want to `INSERT` a new row then you will need to specify values for all the other columns in the table (unless you intend them to be the default, probably `NULL`, value).

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks a million :). It should have been an update statement and not insert.